# How to convert string from database read to List<String>

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm reading data from my db , the specific data in question is a list which was recorded as a String in my database , now i'm trying to read the data by converting the String back into a List , how can i go about doing this wthe snippet of code below :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ref.watch(getDataByIdProvider(widget.ID)).when(
          data: (data) => Scaffold(
            body: ListView(
              children: [
                for (int i = 0; i < data.name.length; i++)//The list in question
                      RadioListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            data.name[i].toString(),
                          ),
                          value: i,
                          groupValue: _selectedRadio,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            _selectedRadio = value as int?;
                          }),],
```

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: so data.name is a String i want to convert it into a List<String>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your string has been separated by ',' character, you can try this way:

```
Column(
          children: [
            ...data.name.split(',').map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
          ],
        ),
```

in this code, I have split my string by ',' char, so dart lang will create a list of items before each ',' char. you can turn Text widget to your desired one.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to store your list as a json string using `jsonEncode` and `jsonDecode` from `dart:convert`

```
final list = ['one', 'to', 'three'];

/// convert your List to json string
final jsonString = jsonEncode(list);
/// Call db.save(jsonString)

/// Call db.get('yourJsonStringKey')
/// Convert json string back to List
final listFromJson = jsonDecode(jsonString);
```